Fail in publish using paho mqtt client
I am trying to send a file through the MQTT protocol using the Paho MQTT as client and the Mosquitto MQTT broker.
Client code to send the message:
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Define the broker details
broker_address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1883
topic = "test"
keep_alive_time = 18 * 60 * 60
# Read the file contents in binary mode
file_path = "D:/FSP/OTA//ftpserverpython/public/u2a16_startup.mot"
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    message = file.read()

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Connect to the broker
client.connect(broker_address, port, keep_alive_time)

# Publish the message as binary data
client.publish(topic, message, retain=True)

# Disconnect from the broker
client.disconnect()

print("Binary file published successfully.")

Client code to receive the message:
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# Define the broker details
broker_address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1883
topic = "test"
keep_alive_time = 18 * 60 * 60
# Read the file contents in binary mode
output_file_path = "D:/FSP/OTA/mqttclient//file/b.mot"
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    # Write the received message payload to a file
    with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(message.payload)
    print(f"File saved to {output_file_path}")

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Connect to the broker
client.connect(broker_address, port, keep_alive_time)

# Publish the message as binary data
client.publish(topic, message, retain=True)

# Set the on_message callback
client.on_message = on_message

# Subscribe to the topic
client.subscribe(topic)

# Start the MQTT loop to process network traffic and dispatch callbacks
client.loop_forever()

First I run the code from receive side and the log from broker:

However, when running publish code the broker does not respond. The log is below:

Therefore, the file is not transmitted successfully.
I use mosquitto -v to run Mosquitto.
I expect the file to be transmitted successfully

Please do not post images of text, post the text and format it. Images are hard to read, impossible for people that need to use screen readers and unsearchable.

oh sorry, this is my first time using stack overflow

You message is bigger than will fit in one network packet (MTU), so you must run the MQTT client loop in the publisher.
You have 2 choices.

use the pre-built function that will publish a single message

import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single(topic, message, hostname=broker, port=port)



Add the start the client loop

def publish_callback(client, userdata, mid):
  client.disconnect()
  print("Binary file published successfully.")

# Create an MQTT client instance
client = mqtt.Client()

# Connect to the broker
client.connect(broker_address, port, keep_alive_time)

client.on_publish = publish_callback

client.loop_start()

# Publish the message as binary data
client.publish(topic, message, retain=True)



I try the first choice and it works. Thank you
For second choice, what is publish_callback function since it has not defined yet

It's a typo, the function called on_publish was miss named. I have edited the answer

thank you for your help

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
